# gtk_message_dialog in a GtkCombo callback

Tags: c, combobox, dialog, gtk

I'm developing an app in C using Gtk. I have a GtkCombo with some restrictions that should launch an error message when user selects wrong entries in the list. The problem is that when callback launches the error message, pop-down string is still open, and if the user moves the mouse over it, the list acts as if all entries under the mouse pointer where clicked. This behavior stops if the user clicks on an empty window area or other GtkWidget. I've tried changing the focus to another widget, launching button_release signal...
Anyone knows how to prevent this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting the signal with `g_signal_connect_after()` instead of `g_signal_connect()`. The callback should run after the combo popdown has finished all its reactions to the click.

Comment: I'm surprised, but with g_signal_connect_after, the dialog appears at the same point as with g_signal_connect.Thank you